# In my logout functionality is an error in Logcat in twitter android app

Tags: android, twitter

My twitter android app is clent base means window base,I am using  twitter 4j otweet.com for my my application.I stored Auth token through shared prefrence.I am getting error in logcat..that is.. twitter4j.TwitterException: Read error: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error.

And my code is:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://api.otweet.com/1/account/end_session.format");
try {
       // Execute HTTP Post Request
       httpclient.execute(httppost);
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit the following link

http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/

Comment: so there is no solution for signout functioanlity.is there any solutions